# Setting an alarm through adb using com.android.deskclock and it's intent com.android.action.SET_ALARM

Tags: android, adb, setalarmclock

I'm trying to set and alarm in the default android clock, com.android.deskclock, using adb. I see that the clock has the intent com.android.action.SET_ALARM with extras EXTRA_HOUR and EXTRA_MINUTES, but I don't know how to send this through adb.

I've tried:

`adb shell am broadcast -n com.android.deskclock/.HandleApiCalls -a com.android.action.SET_ALARM --ei android.intent.extra.alarm.HOUR 17 --ei android.intent.extra.alarm.MINUTES 51`

Comment: Why do you use `am broadcast`? If you want to start a specific intent you never use `am broadcast`, just `am start`.